# Pause CCAction cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

```
self.boxesOnLift = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self init];
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Animation.plist"];
        NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i) 
        {
            [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lift%d.png", i]]];
        }
        self.animation = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
        self.lift = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"lift1.png"];        
        self.lift.position = ccp(0, 0);
        self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
        [self.lift runAction:_walkAction];
        [self addChild:self. lift];
```

Can I pause my animation in current position? Can I resume my action in this position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call `-(void) pauseSchedulerAndActions` or `-(void) onExit` on the CCNode you want to pause. beware though this method may have side effects when you are adding/removing nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the  -(void) resumeSchedulerAndActions to resume the schedulers and its Actions.